# porque se hace peticiones infinitamente en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export const RandomPoke = () => {
  const num=[1,2,3,4]
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState('')
  const fetchPokemon = async (num) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${num}`)
      const data = await response.json()
      console.log(data)
      setPokemon(data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Ha ocurrido un error: ', error)
    }
  }

  for(let i=0;i<num.length;i++){
    fetchPokemon(i);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{pokemon.name}</h2>
      <p>{pokemon.id}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

No entiendo el porque hace peticiones infinitas si solo estoy llamando 4 veces al fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función que llamas 4 veces tiene la instrucción `setPokemon(data)` que actualiza el estado del componente.

Al actualizar el estado del componente, se vuelve a renderizar y cada vez que un componente se renderiza, todo el código dentro de la función se vuelve ejecutar.

Por lo tanto, nuevamente se ejecuta el `for` y la instrucción `setPokemon(data)`. Creaste un bucle infinito.

Si necesitas que tu código se ejecute una única vez o en ciertos casos, debes utilizar [`useEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect).

Por ejemplo, puedes recuperar la información la primera vez que se renderiza un componente así:

```
useEffect(() => {
  for(let i=0;i<num.length;i++){
    fetchPokemon(i);
  }
})
```

Te dejo [un tutorial](https://midu.dev/react-hooks-use-effect-funcionalidad-en-el-ciclo-vida-componentes/) sobre `useEffect`.